# django URLconf current path didn't match

Tags: python, django

Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
polls/ [name='index']
admin/
```

The current path, polls/, didn't match any of these.

My code is...
from (app)polls urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

from (project)mysite urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]
```

from views.py project file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world, you are at the polls index.")
```

Comment: what is the URL that you are trying to access. Home page?

Comment: http://localhost:8000/

Comment: Index is at localhost:800/polls/ since index url is inside `polls.urls` which you have included in project urls with `'polls/'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your view index as a home view, the first page to be rendered on the address localhost:port/.

Then,

In polls.urls.py should be (the same as yours):

```
...
path('', views.index, name='index'),
...
```

And in project.urls.py

```
...
path('', include('polls.urls')),
...
```

It should work.

An extra.
Now if you want to render on the address, lets say, localhost:port/polls

Then your path pattern inside you app.url, (not project.url), would be:

```
path('polls/', polls_view, name='polls')
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: first solution worked....  But still "admin" didn't worked.. url=http://localhost:8000/admin/

Comment: What type of error is it giving this time? Since is about admin now, the admin page require a user table in your database. I suppose you haven't run migrate for your application yet, so in this case your application don't have the tables to work with. If so, type the following in cmd where the file manage.py is located in your application: python manage.py migrate. Now this should work, but If it don't, post the error message that's being showed for you so we can see what it might be.

Answer (score 1):

I am a beginner and I have been troubled for a long time with the same problem.
The key to the problem is the directory:

```
mysite/
    mysite/
    polls/
    ....
```

I suspect that you have created a new file(urls.py) in mysite(The outermost layer of folders) directory and it's invalid. You should modify the file: mysite/mysite/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: where r you ying?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are accessing `localhost:8000`, the search path is empty string `''` and in your project urls, there are only two pattern for `polls` and `admin`. That's why you are getting the error. So you need to access `localhost:8000/polls` to get the result from `index` view of `polls` app.